# Unable to replace object property value with regex

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm trying to replace the value of `model` within this json file.  The json file contains:

```
{
    "model": {
        "template": "model.txt",
        "directory": "app/models",
        "filename": "{{Entity}}.php"
    },
```

I'm trying to use the following regex to replace it and am not able to get it to match...

```
$json = preg_replace('/"model": \{(.*?)\},/i', '"model": false', $json);
```

I recognize i can change this value after it has been decoded and that is the ideal way to handle this.  For various reasons, running this regex would be the simplest way to handle this specific solution.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
        $json = file_get_contents($path);
        $json = preg_replace('/"model": \{(.*?)\},/i', '"model": false', $json);
var_dump($json);
        exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These should work:

The first pattern will not limit the number of items within the `"model"`:

`preg_replace('/("model.*\{.*(\n.*)+?\n.+\},)/', '"model": false', $json);`

This will limit the match specifically to  the number of lines in your example:

`preg_replace('/("model.*\{.*(\n.*){3}\n.+\},)/', '"model": false', $json);`

Comment: Neither of those are finding a match for me.

Comment: Did you look at the examples I linked? Maybe you need additional escape characters within your pattern.

Comment: Doh!  I didn't.  I clearly had pasted something incorrectly because it works now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

given $json the original json content

```
$ajson=json_decode($json);
$ajson['model']=false;
$json=json_encode($ajson);
```

Comment: Doh, sorry.  I should've specified I'm looking for PHP.